# Compare certain properties of an ArrayList and log the duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `Detail class` and I'm adding detail objects to an `ArrayList<Detail>()`. Every `Detail` object has a different line number. What I would like is to compare certain **propeties** of the Detail objects, **log a message** if a duplicate is found in the list and **remove the duplicate** from the list.
I overrided the `equals()` method in the Detail class, but can't figure out how to what to do next.

```
    @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            boolean isEqual = false;
            if(obj instanceof Detail){
                if(this.getInsurancePolicyNo().equals(((Detail) obj).getInsurancePolicyNo()) && this.getCertificateNo().equals(((Detail) obj).getCertificateNo()) && this.getInsuredSurname().equals(((Detail) obj).getInsuredSurname()) && this.getInsuredOtherName().equals(((Detail) obj).getInsuredOtherName()) && this.insuredDOB.equals(((Detail) obj).getInsuredDOB())){
                    isEqual = true;
                }
            }
            return isEqual;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take all the elements and add them to `Set<Details>` using `add` method, one by one

If `add` method returns `false` while inserting a `Details` object, that means that `Detail` object is duplicate, you can ***log*** it

After all items are added to `Set`, then `Set` contains ***unique*** `Details` elements

**Note:** This solution requires that your `Details` class overrides `equals` method

**Edit:** If you wish to find duplicates on completely different properties of `Details` other than what you have used in `equals`, then first

- Define your custom `Comparator` which considers those properties
- Create a `TreeSet` with the created `Comparator`
- Now `TreeSet` will find duplicates using `compareTo` method of the passed `Comparator`

For more info read the documentation of `TreeSet` to find how it finds duplicates/equality

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that the Detail class has other properties other than those defined in my getters. Using a Set in my case will add all the elements. I am searching for duplicates over certain properties.